# iPad: disable animations

Tags: ipad, ios

Is there any way (perhaps involving jailbreaking) to disable all (or at least some) of the transition animations on iPad?

Examples: Homescreen fly-together animation, sliding animations in apps

Comment: Why would you want to? They're part of the experience of the iPad. I'm just curious.

Comment: Cajun, there is no reason you shouldn't be able to customize your own pc. Even Windows 95 had a setting to toggle animations for windowing. Also animations take memory, they screenshot, move the extra graphics, then go back to normal. This often crashes the iPad if it's at maximum memory from say a game, or videos. You don't see it anymore on the newer ones, but I had to code around it earlier. What part of "experience" involves taking away our choices. ok done ranting

Answer (score 1):

Answer: there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you install FakeClockUp and set it to 10x, it almost feels like the animations are disabled.